# Android BackgroundService not start in HTC Desire 620G

Tags: android, service

I created an app with contains backgroundservice, All Phone Device working well, except HTC Desire 620G. Is that phone have Auto-Start Manager like Asus Zenphone 2?

The service is not start in HTC Desire 620G, but in most apps backgroundservice running like whatsapp. Anyone have idea? Thanks

Comment: is the HTC throwing some exception? any useful information from logcat?

Comment: No, exactly no. Thats very weird

Comment: i am fix that problem. just use foreground service instead backgroundservice